# Call ViewController method from App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a method in my ViewController that opens different views based on a pin being present, it works when assigned to a button on an intial view, I can also put it in viewDidLoad method however I am using storyboard and this method viewDidLoad is firing on each view load from modal segues, so instead I am looking to call the method from my appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
It is basically a view redirect on app launch based on the presence of a stored pin value.

I have imported the view controller in app delegate `#import "ViewController.h"`
then using the current code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
ViewController *rootViewController = (ViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
[rootViewController initView];
```

I do this but I am getting the error

No Visible interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'initView'?

Here is my full ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UITextField *emailField;
IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
IBOutlet UITextField *pinField;
IBOutlet UITextField *checkPin;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *ShowEmailList;
-(IBAction)showList:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)checkPin:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)initView:(id)sender;

@end
```

and in my ViewController.m file the method:

```
-(IBAction)initView:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *getPin = [defaults objectForKey:@"Pin"];
    if ([getPin isEqualToString:@""]){
        //do something
    }else{
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to correctly declare my initView method in my ViewController.h file to correct this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add an argument to this method like:

```
[rootViewController initView:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `-(IBAction)initView:(id)sender` is expecting a parameter.

You have two ways to fix this.

- Modify your method signature as `-(IBAction)initView { //source code. }`
- Pass nil or the `AppDelegate` from the caller method

  `[rootViewController initView:nil];` or  `[rootViewController initView:self];`